# Why cast to object before testing for NSNull?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnull

I have the following block in a project I have been moved onto after a previous developer has left

```
NSObject *object = (NSObject *)string;
if([object isEqual:[NSNull null]])
    return @"none"
```

Where `string` is an `NSString *` returned from a dictionary.

While I undertand that NSNull needs to be checked for, can someone tell me why cast to NSObject first?

Comment: Why do you think you need to cast? Have you tried it without casting?

Comment: I don't think I need to, I'm asking if there is a reason someone before me thought it did need casting

Comment: I see this in NSNull's class @interface NSNull : NSObject <NSCopying, NSSecureCoding> so I don't think you gotta typecast before checking, because NSNull is also NSObject but not vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast is unnecessary, although it's usually best to keep an object as an `id` until you know it isn't an `NSNull` (e.g. if you just pulled it out of a collection). If you have an `NSString*` which might actually be `NSNull` it can be confusing. Perhaps the original author wanted to make it clear that the string actually could be something else?

Also, `NSNull` is documented as a singleton, so you could (if you wanted) compare using `==`.

Comment: Is it feasible to use == to compare string in Objective-C ? It can give violating results .Don't you think so ? Generally == is used for numeric comparison.

Comment: But if you are comparing against `[NSNull null]` (the singleton) it will be safe.

Comment: If the string is not null, the == against `[NSNull null]` will be false.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to keep `isEqual` for consistancy but I get why you could use `==` I just wanted to check that no-one could see a good reason for the cast

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your case you no need to type cast string (if it is object of `NSString` class) to `NSObject`.  Anyways, `NSObject` is an root class in Objective-C so it can be all type objects. `NSString` class also inherit from `NSObject`. So `NSObject *object = (NSObject *)string` also valid.

```
if([string isEqual:[NSNull null]])
    return @"none"
```

Also work for you.

The best practice keep your object in **id** generic type instead of `NSObject`.

Answer (score 0):

As @mike-weller said, the best way is:

```
 if(string == [NSNull null]){
     return @"none"
 }
```

'cause NSNull uses the Singleton pattern.